# How to read a system of differential equations from a text file to solve the system with scipy.odeint?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, differential-equations

I have a large (>2000 equations) system of ODE's that I want to solve with python scipy's odeint.

I have three problems that I want to solve (maybe I will have to ask 3 different questions?).
For simplicity, I will explain them here with a toy model, but please keep in mind that my system is large.
Suppose I have the following system of ODE's:

```
dS/dt = -beta*S
dI/dt = beta*S - gamma*I
dR/dt = gamma*I
```

with beta = c*p*I

where c, p and gamma are parameters that I want to pass to odeint.

odeint is expecting a file like this:

```
def myODEs(y, t, params):
    c,p, gamma = params
    beta = c*p
    S = y[0]
    I = y[1]
    R = y[2]
    dydt = [-beta*S*I,
           beta*S*I - gamma*I,
           - gamma*I]  
    return dydt
```

that then can be passed to odeint like this:

```
myoutput = odeint(myODEs, [1000, 1, 0], np.linspace(0, 100, 50), args = ([c,p,gamma], ))
```

I generated a text file in Mathematica, say myOdes.txt, where each line of the file corresponds to the RHS of my system of ODE's, so it looks like this

```
#myODEs.txt

-beta*S*I
beta*S*I - gamma*I
- gamma*I
```

My text file looks similar to what odeint is expecting, but I am not quite there yet.
I have three main problems:

1. How can I pass my text file so that odeint understands that this is the RHS of my system?
2. How can I define my variables in a smart way, that is, in a systematic way? Since there are >2000 of them, I cannot manually define them. Ideally I would define them in a separate file and read that as well.
3. How can I pass the parameters (there are a lot of them) as a text file too?

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834903/sympy-scipy-solving-a-system-of-ordinary-differential-equations-with-different) that is close to my problems 1 and 2 and tried to copy it (I directly put values for the parameters so that I didn't have to worry about my point 3 above):

```
    systemOfEquations = []
    with open("myODEs.txt", "r") as fp :
        for line in fp :
            systemOfEquations.append(line)

    def dX_dt(X, t):
        vals = dict(S=X[0], I=X[1], R=X[2], t=t)
        return [eq for eq in systemOfEquations]

    out = odeint(dX_dt, [1000,1,0], np.linspace(0, 1, 5))
```

but I got the error:

```
    odepack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of          floats.
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: -((12*0.01/1000)*I*S),
```

Edit: I modified my code to:

```
    systemOfEquations = []
    with open("SIREquationsMathematica2.txt", "r") as fp :
        for line in fp :
               pattern = regex.compile(r'.+?\s+=\s+(.+?)$')
               expressionString = regex.search(pattern, line) 
               systemOfEquations.append( sympy.sympify( expressionString) )


    def dX_dt(X, t):
        vals = dict(S=X[0], I=X[1], R=X[2], t=t)
        return [eq for eq in systemOfEquations]

    out = odeint(dX_dt, [1000,1,0], np.linspace(0, 100, 50), )
```

and this works (I don't quite get what the first two lines of the for loop are doing). However, I would like to do the process of defining the variables more automatic, and I still don't know how to use this solution and pass parameters in a text file. Along the same lines, how can I define parameters (that will depend on the variables) inside the dX_dt function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but rather some observations/questions, but they are too long for comments.

`dX_dt` is called many times by `odeint` with a 1d array `y` and tuple `t`.  You provide `t` via the `args` parameter.  `y` is generated by `odeint` and varies with each step.  `dX_dt` should be streamlined so it runs fast.

Usually an expresion like `[eq for eq in systemOfEquations]` can be simplified to `systemOfEquations`.  `[eq for eq...]` doesn't do anything meaningful.  But there may be something about `systemOfEquations` that requires it.

I'd suggest you print out `systemOfEquations` (for this small 3 line case), both for your benefit and ours.  You are using `sympy` to translated the strings from the file into equations.  We need to see what it produces.

Note that `myODEs` is a function, not a file.  It may be imported from a module, which of course is a file.

The point to `vals = dict(S=X[0], I=X[1], R=X[2], t=t)` is to produce a dictionary that the `sympy` expressions can work with.  A more direct (and I think faster) `dX_dt` function would look like:

```
def myODEs(y, t, params):
    c,p, gamma = params
    beta = c*p
    dydt = [-beta*y[0]*y[1],
           beta*y[0]*y[1] - gamma*y[1],
           - gamma*y[1]]  
    return dydt
```

I suspect that the `dX_dt` that runs sympy generated expressions will be a lot slower than a 'hardcoded' one like this.

I'm going add `sympy` tag, because, as written, that is the key to translating your text file into a function that `odeint` can use.

I'd be inclined to put the equation variability in the `t` parameters, rather a list of sympy expressions.

That is replace:

```
    dydt = [-beta*y[0]*y[1],
           beta*y[0]*y[1] - gamma*y[1],
           - gamma*y[1]]
```

with something like

```
    arg12=np.array([-beta, beta, 0])
    arg1 = np.array([0, -gamma, -gamma])
    arg0 = np.array([0,0,0])
    dydt = arg12*y[0]*y[1] + arg1*y[1] + arg0*y[0]
```

Once this is right, then the `argxx` definitions can be move outside `dX_dt`, and passed via `args`.  Now `dX_dt` is just a simple, and fast, calculation.

This whole `sympy` approach may work fine, but I'm afraid that in practice it will be slow.  But someone with more `sympy` experience may have other insights.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I agree that it is faster and better not to use sympy, it doesn't make that much sense to me since I already have my equations in a format that is almost like what odeint is expecting. In fact, what I had before is not even working now :(
 I know that I can define myOdes without using any variables and directly writing the eqs in terms of the vector y, but I have over 2000 variables and writing the eqs in terms of y would be pretty cumbersome and error prone. This is why I want to write the eqs with variables and pass a list of the form:
S = X[0], I = X[1], etc