# read ODEs into scipy's odeint from textfile

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there a way to read ODEs from a text format into an object that scipy's `odeint` can use? this was raised here: [How to read a system of differential equations from a text file to solve the system with scipy.odeint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676313/how-to-read-a-system-of-differential-equations-from-a-text-file-to-solve-the-sys) but this question uses sympy unnecessarily, are there other solutions? scipy's odeint expects a function to be made dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODE has to be a Python function.  Normally that's created with a `def` or as a `lambda`.

`eval` can create a function from a string

```
In [183]: f=eval('lambda x: x**2')
In [184]: f(10)
```

But it is considered unsafe: [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)

But the safe alternative can't create a function

```
In [185]: f=ast.literal_eval('lambda x: x**2')
...
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Lambda object at 0xa749882c>
```

For a more recent discussion of creating a function with `sympy` or direct see: [Parsing Complex Mathematical Functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520470/parsing-complex-mathematical-functions-in-python)

---

The cleanest solution is to write valid Python code in the text file, name it a `.py`, and import it.